# After manually installing Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 15.04, I broke Unity, how can I fix it?

Tags: unity, python

I've done a foolish thing - I did a classic "make install" style installation of Python 3.5. This was a bad idea because it overwrote some of the Python 3 components, including symbolic links. It appears to have broken Unity:

I was able to reinstall all the old Python software using this trick:

```
for pkg in `dpkg --get-selections | egrep -v 'deinstall' | egrep python | awk '{print $1}'`; do  apt-get -y --force-yes install --reinstall $pkg ; done
```

... and I can confirm that the default Python has gone back to 2.7, however this doesn't seem to have fixed my window manager!

It currently looks like this:

[image: This is what my desktop looked like after a reboot]

How can I recover Unity. Failing that, is there some other Window manager that I can

Update 0: Following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673870/problems-with-apt-dependencies-after-install-of-python-3-5) helped me remove the bogus entry for Python 3.5 that checkinstall put there. Now I can at least install Mate as a temporary measure.